# UDK is very slow, 8fps

Tags: performance, windows-xp, unreal-development-kit, bootcamp

I'm running UDK on Bootcamp, and it runs at around 8fps. (I envy those smooth UDK users)

These are my specs:

Intel 2.3Ghz

SM3 Video Card

2GB RAM

Windows XP SP2

If you look [here](http://udk.com/download), it should run ok. However when I run the demos it is also unplayable.

I've no idea what do do. Help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using bootcamp should not mean much, it's fully capable of utilizing the full capacity of your hardware. However, people do complain that their computer is slower after use of bootcamp, so maybe it has some effect.

I'm also going to take a wild guess and say you are running a Macbook. They have a tendency of becoming really hot when used at full capacity, and this slows the performance drastically. (This is from personal experience)

But your main problem is your hardware. 2GB RAM should be enough to play the games made with UDK, but keep in mind that when you test your own game the editor is still running in the background, and uses up almost all of your RAM.

This, combined with the fact that you have a partitioned harddrive is probably what's causing the bad performance. 
The only solution would be to get better hardware from what I can see, and from my own experience..

Answer (score 0):

What video card do you use?
UDK can be launched in dx11 (it's default) mode? this is quite a big load

Comment: Oh, sorry.Windows XP does not support directX 11.

Answer (score 0):

UDK should be defaulting to dx9, and even then it wouldn't run at all if it were dx10 or 11 on  xp, your video card obviously isn't up to the task, or the bootcamp drivers for your mac on windows may be out of date